# Backgroundworker not Rendering Window fluently

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I just got into WPF and am currently trying my luck with the Background worker, so I figured I'd just open any file using the `FileOpenDialog`, loop through all the bytes inside the file and report the total progress via `worker.ReportProgress` in percentage ... alas, this only works for like ~20 times and then it gets really stuck and suddenly stops at 100%.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace BitStream
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private int bytes = 0;
    private long length = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void selectFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if ((bool)ofd.ShowDialog())
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
            this.length = fi.Length;
            bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
            bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            Stream str = ofd.OpenFile();

            bw.RunWorkerAsync(str);
        }
    }

    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Stream str = (Stream)e.Argument;
        int singleByte = 0;
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                new Action(() =>
                {
                    int currentProgress = 0;
                    while ((singleByte = str.ReadByte()) != -1)
                    {

                        label1.Content = singleByte;
                        bytes++;

                        currentProgress = Convert.ToInt32(((double)bytes) / length * 100);
                        if (currentProgress > progress)
                        {
                            progress = currentProgress;
                            ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(progress);
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }
                    }
                }

            ), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);
    }

    private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Content = e.ProgressPercentage + "% completed";
    }

    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Labels 1 and 2 are there for showing the current byte and the current progress in %.

Feel free to also criticize every other aspect of my code, I just got started with WPF today.

Edited DoWork-Method:

```
 private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Stream str = (Stream)e.Argument;
        int singleByte = 0;

        int currentProgress = 0;
        while ((singleByte = str.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                new Action(() =>
                {
                    label1.Content = singleByte;
                }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);
            bytes++;

            currentProgress = Convert.ToInt32(((double)bytes) / length * 100);
            if (currentProgress > progress)
            {
                progress = currentProgress;
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                new Action(() =>
                {
                    ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(progress);


                }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);
                Thread.Sleep(500);        
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: Am I misreading your code or are you putting the UI thread to sleep for 100ms for every byte of the file you read?

Comment: You read correctly, I just tried to see whether this had anything to do with it not updating as fluently because of me spamming the thread with ReportProgress-Calls.

Comment: Yeah but now you're doing everything on the UI thread - there's no point in using a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: So just to be clear, the DoWork method is invoked on a background thread. When you call Invoke/BeginInvoke on a Dispatcher that means that delegate that you are invoking will be executed on the UI thread.

Comment: Huh, well now that explains a lot. I've been wondering what this Invoke-Voodoo was doing - 5 minutes ago I was just happy I got rid of that Crossthreading-Error.

Comment: I posted a modified version of your code. Not sure that you really want to marshall to the ui thread for every byte but that is the gist of what you might do.

Comment: It works now! Updated my question with the correct code for you to see whether there are any errors left.

Comment: ReportProgress need not be invoked on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming you really want to make a cross thread call for each byte (which I wouldn't recommend), the code would look something like:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Stream str = (Stream)e.Argument; 
    int singleByte = 0; 
    int currentProgress = 0; 
    while ((singleByte = str.ReadByte()) != -1) 
    { 

       bytes++; 
       this.Dispatcher.Invoke( 
            new Action(() => 
            { 
                    label1.Content = singleByte; 
            } 

        ), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render); 

        currentProgress = Convert.ToInt32(((double)bytes) / length * 100); 
        if (currentProgress > progress) 
        { 
            progress = currentProgress; 
            ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(progress); 
            Thread.Sleep(100); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The idea being that you can only manipulate a DispatcherObject on the thread on which it was created.

Comment: I assume sender.ReportProgress should also be inside an Invoke-Method since it calls to a function that uses a DispatcherObject, right?
Edit: Just saw your comment ... why does this not need to be invoked?

Answer (score 1):

First thought is you aren't disposing the return from the openfiledialog so the more times you run it the more resources you throw away...
I would have thrown the filename at the worker and then let it manage the resource, but

```
using(Stream s = ofd.OpenFileDalog())
{
   get length and such
}
// run up woker pass filename.
```

in your calling code will solve the problem, as I'm assuming you are using length to sort out your progress bar.